# Deleting temp files by using python code

Tags: python-2.7

I want to delete the temporavary files but if i run my code it is completely deletining the Temp folder only,i want to delete the files 
inside the temp folder

```
import os
import shutil
from shutil import rmtree

yourpath = 'C:\\Users\\SHIVAPRASAD\\Appdata\Local\Temp'
folder_size=0


for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(yourpath):
    for name in files:
    filename = os.path.join(root, name)
    folder_size +=os.path.getsize(filename)
    print "Folder size in mb is\n",str((folder_size/(1024*1024.0)))


 for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(yourpath):
      for name in files:
      print (os.path.join(root,name))


print 'Do u want to delete temporavary file of size',str((folder_size/(1024*1024.0))),'MB'' ' 'y/n'
n=raw_input()
if n=='y':
  shutil.rmtree(r'C:\\Users\\SHIVAPRASAD\\Appdata\Local\Temp')
  print 'succesfully removed the temp files'
else:
   print 'you have not removed the temporavary file'
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to delete the temp files like ccleanaer does,The code is running fine to print to temp files and also to print the size,but the third option is to delete temp files that is not working well and good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html:

> shutil.rmtree(path[, ignore_errors[, onerror]])
>
> Delete an entire directory tree;

that's what your program does but not what you want

with `os.remove()` you can remove your files:

```
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(yourpath):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
    print 'Do u want to delete temporary file of size', str((folder_size/(1024*1024.0))), 'MB'' ' 
    n = raw_input('y/n >')
    if n =='y':
        for file in  files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
        print 'succesfully removed the temp files'
    else:
        print 'you have not removed the temporary files'
```